# Simulate a 13 inch display on 15 inch MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, display

Is there any way to simulate a 13 inch display on a 15 inch MacBook Pro? Some tool that would resize all windows, the dock and menu to take up less space? Reason is I am thinking of buying a 13 inch MacBook Pro and want to see how it is working with a smaller screen.

Comment: Tools of choice for the task at hand: Hammer or chainsaw.

Comment: Why not go into a store and use one for 15 minutes? No one is going to kick you off if you're a genuine potential buyer.

Comment: @mada.eve Oh I have, but I want to try it out with my own applications and general setup.

Answer (score 0):

Take a screenshot, change your desktop picture to just black. Use qucklook & drag the screenshot smaller.

Comment: Not a bad suggestion. But I'd still like to actively experience using a computer with a smaller amount of screen space, if possible.

Comment: Try resize the window of app you use to the width of the keyboard, it would be close the width of the 13 inch laptop.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @atapaka It provides the simplest workaround without just saying ' get a 13" display' , or 'this cannot be done'.